# Excel: Search multiple columns for multiple words

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a big list of movies, each one has 1-8 keywords in 8 diffrent columns (Key1-Keyw8).

I now need to sort through all movies for movies which have let's say 3 keywords.

Example:
I want to find all movies with the keywords: Water, Ship, Clouds.

Now every film that has all those 3 keywords should be displayed. The keywords can be in any column.

I found out that I can do filters like this with advanced filter, but I now have a problem with how they work.

If I put a word in the first column, it will only search if the Keyw1 contains the word:
[image: Keyw1 is searched]

I then thought I could simply make multiple searches:
[image: Keyword copyed to every column]

This kinda works, it gives me some results. But it also leaves some rows out:
[image: Some rows where found.]

But some fell through:
[image: Row 2 contains the keyword, but did not get displayed]

Row 2 contains the keyword, but did not get displayed.

Even if this would work, if I want to search for 8 keywords, I would need to duplicate the word 40'000 times to find all results.

What am I doing wrong? Or how else could I do it?

Comment: I think it's easier to do this with VBA.

Comment: You are not setting up your Advanced Filter criteria range properly.  Carefully read HELP for that function to see how it's done.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have updated the question, as another further problem occured when I filter correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to look for so many keywords, you need a different strategy.  You can modify below for any number of keywords to be found at the same time

I would set up a Helper column, with a formula that evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE`, and then filter on that.

For example:

- KeyWords is a `Named Range` referring to `$G$2:$G$3`

[image]

- In the table below:

[image]

`E2 (FilterCol): =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(KeyWords,A2:D2,0)))=COUNTA(KeyWords)`

- Fill Down and then filter on `TRUE`

[image]

You can certainly Hide the FilterCol, or put it somewhere distant on the worksheet where it won't be seen

Comment: I thought it worked, but it did not. http://prntscr.com/nr359d Like you can see on row 5, there is no Keyword killer, but it still is true. KeyWord Name Range is set from K2-K9.

Comment: @TimothyLukasH. That is because you didn't use the formula I recommended. `MATCH(KeyWord,KeyWord,0)` will always return a Match

Comment: You are right, sorry I didn't read the A2:D2 wrongly. Now it works. Thank you very much!